# O que é arquitetura serverless?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, cloud

Alguém poderia explicar resumidamente o que é uma arquitetura Serverless? Depois de ler algumas páginas [aqui](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/), fiquei na dúvida. Do [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing), basicamente resume o que se encontra por aí:

> [...] is a cloud computing execution model in which the cloud provider dynamically manages the allocation of machine resources

Mas isso não parece ser muito diferente dos serviços AWS. Ou também podemos entender que parece se tratar de uma forma de Amazon Lambda, onde se guarda funções que rodam em NodeJS (e outras línguas) e retornam resultados de operação CRUD. No final das contas é tipo uma API? Estou meio confuso.

## Update

Depois de escrever esse post eu continuei com minhas pesquisas e encontrei esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71cd5XerKss) muito interessante e que corrobora com o que foi dito aqui até agora.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A própria Amazon fez suas definições dessa arquitetura [aqui](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/) (ênfase minha)

> construa e rode aplicações sem [ter que] **pensar** sobre servidores

Não é que seja sem servidores, é que o foco nele será menor.

O Amazon Lambda fica em voga quando falamos de serverless e AWS pois você escreve código sem se preocupar com em que servidor, container ou máquina virtual ele vai rodar.

O grande ganho se dá no desenvolvimento da aplicação, já que o foco será nele e não em configuração de servidor e esses blá-blá-blás de DevOps. Vale uma leitura na [cultura NoOps](https://www.infoq.com/br/news/2012/03/NoOps). Do site da AWS, mesma página que citei anteriomente:

> diminuir a sobrecarga [de gerenciamento de servidores] possibilita que os desenvolvedores tenham energia e tempo para gastarem no desenvolvimento de bons produtos que escalam e são confiáveis

Não tem como aplicar tudo usando essa arquitetura, existem casos (talvez a maioria), que o melhor seria gerenciar o servidor, a escalabilidade e a disponibilidade da aplicação.

Na definição que você trouxe do Wikipedia, posso dar ênfase

> is a cloud computing execution model in which **the cloud provider dynamically manages** the allocation of machine resources

É o Azure, a AWS ou a Google Cloud Platform quem gerenciaria o servidor em questões de escalabilidade, alocação de recursos, localização e etc, enquanto você e seu time focariam no desenvolvimento da aplicação.

- [Arquitetura sem Servidor – Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/functions/)
- [Computação sem servidor – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/serverless/)
- [Serverless Architecture – Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/serverless/)
- [Function as a service – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service)

É um paradigma interessante de desenvolvimento, porém, obviamente, há controvérsias. É bom estar no controle também. Questione tudo!

> "Um ser humano sem dúvidas não evolui. O questionamento é o primeiro passo para nos abrirmos para o novo." - Roberto Shinyashiki

Comment: Eu creio que somos forçados a fazer stateless assim, né? Quando se gerencia o servidor de aplicações, tem gente que vai fazendo algo que acaba por ser stateful.

Answer (score 13):

Mais um nome marketeiro e errado. Eu gosto da ideia de não ter servidor, mas não é o caso deste termo.

É uma forma onde você "compra" serviços e não estrutura. Você não tem que saber nada sobre o servidor, onde está, capacidade, nada. Você só usa e paga pelo que usar individualmente, pode ser até mesmo a execução de função que você desenvolveu e subiu na nuvem. Você não tem que saber nenhum detalhe, você é só usuário do serviço.

O AWS, Azure e Google Cloud Platform estão fortalecendo cada vez mais essa ideia, até porque provavelmente é mais vantajoso financeiramente para eles. Não tudo, claro, mas muitos dos serviços destes e outros fornecedores de nuvem são baseados no mal-chamado *serverless*.

Sobre a API, depende do serviço. A AWS Lambda não é bem uma API no sentido que deve estar pensando, até porque a maioria das pessoas entendem API do jeito errado. Até tem uma API para manipular o serviço, mas o que você consome não é uma API, pelo menos fornecida por eles. Pode ser uma API, mas que você desenvolveu e colocou lá. Mas tem outros serviços que são APIs deles.

Comment: Tbm concordo com a sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

## Somewhere Back in Time

### Anos 90

Até a década de 1990, as empresas tinham que comprar servidores físicos para hospedar seus sistemas. E também tinham que dispor de um espaço físico para acomodá-los, chamado de **data center** ou então de centro de processamento de dados, que era inclusive o termo mais comum nessa época. Atualmente, costuma-se também chamar esse modelo de **on-premises**, pois os servidores estão localizados nas próprias instalações da empresa que vai usar o sistema.

<sup>*em inglês, a expressão ***on premises*** designa os terrenos e as edificações de propriedade de uma empresa).</sup>

Em seguida, mas ainda na década de 1990, começaram a surgir data centers que hospedavam servidores físicos para terceiros. Com isso, não era mais preciso ter espaços próprios para instalar máquinas e, consequentemente, não era preciso se preocupar com instalações elétricas, climatização, no-breaks, acesso à Internet, controle de acesso físico às máquinas, etc. Esses data centers são chamados de **colocation**, pois no mesmo local são instalados servidores de várias empresas.

### Anos 2000

Prosseguindo, no início dos anos 2000, surgiram as **plataformas de cloud** oferecendo servidores virtuais para as empresas contratantes. Assim, a compra ou aluguel de servidores físicos deixou de ser obrigatória. Isso passou a ser responsabilidade das empresas de cloud, que alugam servidores virtuais que executam em cima de suas máquinas físicas.

O conceito de **serverless** pode ser visto como a próxima evolução desse processo. Basicamente, a empresa que precisa desenvolver um sistema implementa um conjunto de funções – normalmente, chamadas de **funções serverless** ou **funções lambda** – e copia as mesmas para um sistema de cloud. Portanto, não existe mais aluguel de servidores, sejam eles virtuais ou físicos. E as funções serverless podem ser invocadas por aplicações clientes do sistema ou então serem automaticamente chamadas após a ocorrência de determinados eventos.

Uma figura para ilustrar melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Um conceito pensado erroneamente

O nome **serverless** explica-se pelo fato de que os **desenvolvedores não precisam se preocupar com instalação, configuração e escalabilidade de servidores**, sejam eles físicos ou virtuais. Ou seja, para ficar bem claro, **continuam existindo servidores**, mas eles são mantidos e configurados pelas empresas de cloud.

Exemplo: ao se usar um serviço LAMBDA da AWS, você tira a responsabilidade do desenvolvedor de analisar, configurar e monitorar um servidor, EC2 na AWS por exemplo, e essas preocupações ficam por conta da AWS, ficando apenas a cargo do desenvolvedor realizar as configurações básicas de uma função LAMBDA.

## Como se gera renda com Serverless?

Com serverless, paga-se pelo **tempo de execução das funções serverless**. Ou seja, apenas quando ocorre um determinado evento ou chamada é que as funções são carregadas, executadas, encerradas e cobradas do cliente.

Esse modelo de pagamento é semelhante ao de serviços utilitários, como energia elétrica. Por exemplo, você somente paga o que usa de eletricidade (ou deveria). Se não tiver nenhum uso no mês, sua conta será zero ou então igual a um valor mínimo. E se precisar aumentar o seu consumo, dentro de certos limites, você tem certeza de que a companhia de eletricidade irá prover a energia necessária.

Porém, mesmo não havendo pagamento pelo tempo de ociosidade das funções, uma solução baseada em serverless não é sempre mais barata. Isso vai depender também dos preços cobrados pelo provedor de cloud para execução de funções serverless e para aluguel de servidores virtuais.

## Características de Funções Serverless

Funções serverless têm as seguintes características principais:

- Elas são **stateless**, isto é, elas não guardam qualquer estado entre uma execução e outra. No entanto, elas podem acessar serviços externos, como bancos de dados e serviços de envio de e-mail.
- Elas executam por um intervalo de tempo máximo, normalmente, da ordem de alguns minutos. Após esse intervalo, elas são automaticamente encerradas pela plataforma de cloud. Isso vem como uma medida de segurança por parte do provedor para evitar que uma função consuma muitos recursos de máquina por muito tempo.
- Elas podem ser implementadas em uma variedade de linguagens de programação (JavaScript/Node.js, Ruby, Python, Java...).

## CALMA!!!

Nem tudo são flores. Uma arquitetura serverless também possui desvantagens. Vou citar algumas que considero (pelo meu conhecimento) como maiores problemas:

- Complexidade de gerenciar uma arquitetura constituída por um grande número de pequenas funções. Na verdade, cada função serverless é uma aplicação autônoma, no sentido de que ela deve importar todas as dependências necessárias para a sua execução. Isso inclui bibliotecas de terceiros e também outros módulos da aplicação, como módulos de domínio.
- Maior latência, principalmente na primeira execução de uma função serverless. Essa latência adicional deve-se à necessidade de criar um container para executar uma função serverless e, em seguida, copiar o código da função para o container criado. Só então a função é executada. A literatura de serverless refere-se a esse problema como **problema da partida a frio** (cold start problem). Ele é mais crítico na primeira execução de uma função, pois depois o container pode ser mantido em cache por um certo tempo.
- Riscos de alto acoplamento com a plataforma de cloud, tornando mais difícil uma mudança para uma outra plataforma. Esse problema é chamado de dependência de fornecedores (vendor lock-in). O acoplamento com a plataforma de cloud surge quando a função serverless faz uso de outros serviços oferecidos pela plataforma, como autenticação, filas de mensagens, logging, bancos de dados, etc.

## Uma boa alternativa

Claramente a arquitetura **serverless** se apresenta como uma boa alternativa para determinados contextos, principalmente pela sua simplicidade em relação a um servidor, mas como qualquer outra solução de tecnologias, tem as suas vantagens e desvantagens. Cabe ao engenheiro de software analisar seus pontos fortes e fracos antes de optar pelo seu uso. Por exemplo, antes de ter a brilhante (ou não) ideia de migrar um sistema monolito para micros serviços, talvez adotar uma arquitetura serverless possa se tornar uma boa opção. Certas partes do sistema monolito podem ser migradas gradualmente para funções lambdas. Pode-se criar ou separar times de desenvolvedores voltados apenas para manter e criar essas funções. Reduzir custos. Dentre outras coisas, mas sempre atento aos *tradeoffs* que esta tecnologia acaba gerando.

Comment: Essa resposta foi subestimada, merecia mais votos.